# Can pheromones be received other than by odor?

Tags: human-physiology

I'm trying to understand how deodorants affect pheromones in humans.

Wiki states:

[Axilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axilla)

> In humans, the formation of body odor happens mostly in the axillary
>   region. These odorant substances serve as pheromones which play a role
>   related to mating.

[Deodorant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deodorant)

> A deodorant is a substance applied to the body to prevent body odor caused by the bacterial breakdown of perspiration in armpits, feet, and other areas of the body.

Can the opposite sex receive pheromones if a person uses crystal deodorant (doesn't have a fragrance; doesn't block sweating; prevents body odor by creating an invisible, protective barrier against odor-causing bacteria)?

Comment: Despite the Wikipedia page you link to, the existence of human pheromones is still a matter of [debate](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/03/do-human-pheromones-actually-exist). For the most part human body odor comes from the breakdown products of sweat and skin by bacteria. These smells *may* play a role in sexual attraction, but they aren't strictly pheromones since the odorants aren't actually secreted by humans, but by bacteria that live on our skin.

Answer (score -1):

We have only 5 senses, a 6th sense has been controversial, and some 6th senses are sometimes reported in new research in newspapers, but none have been conclusively been added to the clearly known 5. There is a second olfactory organ that deals with social signals in other animals, that we possess, the vomeronasal organ.

Pheromones are only olfactory molecules, so you can't get them other than by catching molecules and analysing them, i.e. smelling.

Humans react very strongly by attraction to some perfumes other than pheremones, and you arent supposed to block all your smells, only make them containable, a bit is probably a good thing.

Scientists did publish a study claiming that people can tell if they make a good immune response / metabolic genetic combo with a partner from smelling a potential partner's t-shirt.

Comment: "We have only 5 senses, a 6th sense has been controversial" - This is meaningless. There are well over 5 senses. The 5 senses thing is a biology myth taught to children.

Comment: Are the pheromones in the bad scent after sweating? As I said, take for example, deodorants that don't block sweat but "disable" bacteria. Can opposite sex catch these molecules or deodorants block them?

Comment: Meaningless? It's BioPhysics categorization, and current affairs, news headlines, So, No, Actually it is a Bio-Physics subject. And Artmal is not a doctor, no one even understands the question very scientifically, If you know a kinder reply to him, give it. Energy is transmitted in 5 major groups into the human mind: Chemical scent of the air, and chemical scent of taste, Soundwaves, Photons, Kinetic Energy.